# How to make in-focus terminal windows more obvious?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I use the default gnome-terminal. My workflow is to have two terminal windows opening side by side. The problem is I'm often typing in the wrong side which is not in focus.

Is there a way to make in-focus terminal window more obvious, by, for example, using different background colors for in-focus ones and out-of-focus ones?

Or are there any other terminal applications that have this functionality?

Comment: Can you provide more details? I tried `compiz configuration manager` as well as installed `compiz-plugins` but haven't found the right options to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I can use the `Dim Inactive` in `Compiz` to make inactive windows dimmer. This works not only for `gnome-terminal` but also for any application windows.

BTW, The default dimming speed is slow. I used `Fading Windows` section in `Compiz`  to speed it up.